# I have this error in QT creator: Could not find qmake configuration file linux-g++-64

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator

I will work with QT 4.8.6 and i install from Linux Mint software center this three: qt4-dev-tools, qt creator and qt4-make. But when i will open a project (.pro) programmed with qt4 i obtain this errors on qt creator:

```
Error while parsing file /home/daniel/SpiderOak Hive/Estudio de Desarrollo de interfaces/QT/Ejercicios QT/tema02/application/application.pro. Giving up.
Could not find qmake configuration file default.
Could not find qmake configuration file linux-g++-64.
Error while parsing file /home/daniel/SpiderOak Hive/Estudio de Desarrollo de interfaces/QT/Ejercicios QT/tema02/application/application.pro. Giving up.
```

Yes, i'm a newbie.
What can i do for solve this?

Edit: Here is the image when i will load the project.
[image]

Answer (score 23):

I will paste here just some theory for further debugging, because there is not enough info to solve issue.

#### How the build process works?

1. `qmake` reads special "spec" file which contains information about what compiler You want to use etc etc etc
2. Using these options `qmake` generates `Makefile`
3. After that, `make` or `cmake` calls compiler, linker etc and builds Your project.

#### What your error means?

```
"Could not find qmake configuration file default."
```

means exactly that: qmake could not find this "compiler configuration" file from step 1.

#### Where these files are located?

In $QTDIR/mkspecs folder where $QTDIR is a place where QT is installed. You should check this folder and see a lot of subfolders there, including some which are missing.

#### How can I find $QTDIR?

Just run `qmake --version` and You will find where $QTDIR is located. On my machine, for example, it's, for example, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5`

Warning: there can be A LOT OF DIFFERENT `qmake` executables installed in Your system (one for each qt version!). So, first of all, see what qmake executable You qtcreator uses!

#### So what shall I do?

1. Figure where is Your $QTDIR. Ensure that Your QT creator knows it
2. Check `mkspecs` folder and see what spec files are presented. If there is no such folder or you don't have the spec for Your compiler -- Your QT installation is broken.

Answer (score 10):

To resolve this specific issue:

```
Could not find qmake configuration file default.
```

Review your Qt Creator default kit:

1. Tools > Options ...
2. Select Build & Run
3. Select your preferred kit
4. Click "Make Default" button
5. Click OK

Now reopen your project.

Answer (score 3):

Check your qmake location in QtCreator (tool->build&run->Qt Version)

if it's correct check your specs ($QtSDKLocation/$GCC_Version/gcc_64/mkspecs)